# which way is better to structure a image caption?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I am implementing the HTML of an image with a caption and I am not sure what the best idea is to build the markup for.

I am not sure if i should use a separate div with a class attached to it and then just add a

with the text.

```
<div class="caption">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
```

over using only one html markup element that would also be able to solve the problem - but could lack in flexibility on the future.

```
<p class="caption">Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

Any ideas or suggestions from your side?

Comment: Please describe why you think the one is better than the other.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML5 for images you can use figure and figcaption:

```
<figure>
    <img src='image.jpg' alt='image alt' />
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```